# I dont want to display all the records of table in listview but I want to display records of only particular customer in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, sqflite

I have a screen which shows list of customers using listview. Next when I click on a customer I want to show the notes(records) only of that particular customer(customerId) in next screen in listview. I know how to display all the records of table. but how to display only certain records?? Neither there is any error nor the listview is being displayed. I dont know where am I going wrong.

```
 List<CustomerNote> cnoteList;
      int count = 0;
       if (cnoteList == null) {
      cnoteList = List<CustomerNote>();
      updateCustomerNotes();
    }
```

db_service.dart

```
    Future<List<CustomerNote>> getCustomerNotes(int customer) async {
    await DB.init();
    var res = await DB.rawQuery("noteDetails WHERE custId = '$customer'");
    int count = res.length;
    List<CustomerNote> cnotelist = List<CustomerNote>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      cnotelist.add(CustomerNote.fromMap(res[i]));
    }
    return cnotelist;
  }
```

People_List.dart   //this is the file which displays list of customers

```
import 'package:customer/models/Note.dart';
import 'package:customer/models/addCustomer.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/New_Note.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/Note_info.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/User_Settings.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/add_person.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:customer/utils/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class People_List extends StatefulWidget{


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return People_ListState();
  }

}

class People_ListState extends State<People_List> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  DBService dbService = DBService();
  List<AddCustomer> customerList;
  int count = 0;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var _isSelectedItemIndex;
  TextEditingController _searchQuery;
  bool _isSearching = false;
  String searchQuery = "Search query";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
  }

  void _startSearch() {
    print("open search box");
    ModalRoute
        .of(context)
        .addLocalHistoryEntry(new LocalHistoryEntry(onRemove: _stopSearching));

    setState(() {
      _isSearching = true;
    });
  }

  void _stopSearching() {
    _clearSearchQuery();

    setState(() {
      _isSearching = false;
    });
  }

  void _clearSearchQuery() {
    print("close search box");
    setState(() {
      _searchQuery.clear();
      updateSearchQuery("Search query");
    });
  }

  Widget _buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    var horizontalTitleAlignment =
    Platform.isIOS ? CrossAxisAlignment.center : CrossAxisAlignment.start;

    return new InkWell(
      onTap: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: horizontalTitleAlignment,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchField() {
    return new TextField(
      controller: _searchQuery,
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search...',
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),
      ),
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
      onChanged: updateSearchQuery,
    );
  }

  void updateSearchQuery(String newQuery) {

    setState(() {
      searchQuery = newQuery;
    });
    print("search query " + newQuery);

  }

  List<Widget> _buildActions() {

    if (_isSearching) {
      return <Widget>[
        new IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_searchQuery == null || _searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              return;
            }
            _clearSearchQuery();
          },
        ),
      ];
    }
    return <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: _startSearch,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (customerList == null) {
      customerList = List<AddCustomer>();
      updateListView();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: _isSearching ? const BackButton() : null,
        title: _isSearching ? _buildSearchField() : _buildTitle(context),
        actions: _buildActions(),

      ),
      body:getCustomerListView(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          navigateToCustomer(AddCustomer(), 'Add Person');
        },

        child: const Icon(Icons.add),

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:Row (
      children: <Widget>[
        buildNavBarItem(Icons.home,0,"Home"),
        buildNavBarItem(Icons.fiber_new_rounded,1,"Upcoming"),
        buildNavBarItem(Icons.history,2,"History"),
        buildNavBarItem(Icons.account_circle,3,"Account"),

      ],
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView getCustomerListView() {

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(

            /*trailing: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: getPriorityColor(this.noteList[position].priority),
              child: getPriorityIcon(this.noteList[position].priority),
            ),*/

            title: Text(this.customerList[position].custName, style: titleStyle,),
            //subtitle: Text(this.customerList[position].date),

            onTap: () {

            },

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


  void navigateToCustomer(AddCustomer customer, String title) async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return AddPerson(customer, title);
    }));

    if (result == true) {
      updateListView();
    }
  }
  void updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = DB.init();
    dbFuture.then((database) {

      Future<List<AddCustomer>> customerListFuture = dbService.getCustomerList();
      customerListFuture.then((customerList) {
        setState(() {
          this.customerList = customerList;
          this.count = customerList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  Widget buildNavBarItem(IconData icon,int index,title) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        _isSelectedItemIndex=index;
        if(_isSelectedItemIndex==3) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => User_Settings()));
        }
      });
      },
      child: Container(
          height: height * 0.09,
          width: width / 4,
          decoration: index==_isSelectedItemIndex?BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 4,color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.015),
            ],begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,end: Alignment.topCenter)
          ):BoxDecoration(),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                child: Icon(icon,
                  color: index==_isSelectedItemIndex? Theme.of(context).primaryColor:Colors.black54,
                ),

              ),
              Text(title)
            ],)),
    );
  }
}
```

Note_Info.dart

```
    class Note_Info extends StatefulWidget{
  final String appBarTitle;
  final AddCustomer customer;

  Note_Info(this. customer, this.appBarTitle);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return Note_InfoState(this.customer,this.appBarTitle);
  }

}

class Note_InfoState extends State<Note_Info> {
  CustomerNote note=CustomerNote();
  DBService dbService = DBService();
  List<CustomerNote> cnoteList;
  int count = 0;
  String appBarTitle;
  AddCustomer customer;

  Note_InfoState(this.customer, this.appBarTitle);

  PickedFile _imageFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  bool rememberMe = false;
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController custNameController = TextEditingController();


    
      void getImage(ImageSource source) async {
        final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(
            source: source);
        setState(() {
          _imageFile = pickedFile;
        });
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        if (noteList == null) {
          noteList = List<CustomerNote>();
          updateCustomerNotes();
        }
        var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        custNameController.text = customer.custName;
        return DefaultTabController(
            length: 4,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  actions: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
    
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => NewNote()));
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                body: Container(
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(controller: custNameController,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: Row(children: [
                            ImageProfile(),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.call,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  size: 45,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
    
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
    
                          ],),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: AppBar(
                            bottom: TabBar(
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(
                                  text: "All",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Pending",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Cancelled",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Completed",
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
    
                        // create widgets for each tab bar here
                        Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(
                            children: [
                              // first tab bar view widget
                              Container(
                                child: getNoteListView(),
    
                              ),
    
                              // second tab bar view widget
                              Container(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Pending Items',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Cancelled',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
    
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Completed',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 55.0,
                            width: 200,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              elevation: 2,
    
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                              color: Theme
                                  .of(context)
                                  .primaryColorDark,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Text('Save', textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  //_reset();
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]
                  ),
                )
            ));
      }
    void updateCustomerNotes() {

    final Future<Database> dbFuture = DB.init();
    dbFuture.then((database) {
      int customerId=customer.custId;
      Future<List<CustomerNote>> noteListFuture = dbService.getCustomerNotes(customerId);
      noteListFuture.then((cnoteList) {
        setState(() {
          this.cnoteList = cnoteList;
          //this.count = cnoteList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  ListView getNoteListView() {

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(

            title: Text(this.cnoteList[position].note, style: titleStyle,),

            subtitle: Text(this.cnoteList[position].date),

            trailing: GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.grey,),
              onTap: () {

              },
            ),

            onTap: () {

            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

    
      void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) {
    
        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
      Widget ImageProfile() {
        return Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 80.0,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
    
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get some specific data from the server then you need to provide (where: ) in your query such as

```
   List<Map> result = await db.query(
        DatabaseHelper.table,
        columns: columnsToSelect,
        where: whereString,
        whereArgs: whereArguments);

    // print the results
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));
    // {_id: 1, name: Bob, age: 23}
  }
```

**Note your query can be different from the above one.**

and if you want to get the same specific data from already fetched data then also you need to use the where clause such as

```
final outData = responseData.where((i) => i.userId == customerId).toList();
```

and then pass the outData to next page through params.

Comment: I didnt get u. Where should i add this code?? Can u b a bit specific with my code. Should i add this code in db_helper or People_List.dart??

Comment: Hi @FathimaShafana if I'm not wrong the getNoteList() function inside db_helper have the query to get noteList from db. So to get the list of all notes of a particular Customer using customerId, you have to add a where clause in your getNoteList() functions query.  --> where: 'customerId= xyz',  <-- something like this. I think you are using sqflite so you can search how to add where clause in sqflite query if you are still not able to run your query. And if you are still not able to solve it please let me know.

Comment: Actually now i have added the query but its not displaying I dont kno where m I wrong I will edit the question n show.